# ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence [python 3]

Tags: python, python-3.x, runtime-error

IS the list being nullified after calculating sum??

```
t = int(input())
while t > 0:
    n,m=map(int,input().split())
    a=map(int,input().split())
    l,o=sum(a),max(a)
    print(l)
    if ((o * n)-l) == m:
        print("YES")
    else:
        print((o * n)-l)
        print("NO")
    t = t-1
```

Answer (score 3):

In Python 3 `map()` returns an iterator (unlike Python 2). The `sum()` function iterated over all the results already, and the iterator is now empty:

```
>>> sample = '1 2 3'
>>> map(int, sample.split())
<map object at 0x10523b2e8>
>>> a = map(int, sample.split())
>>> list(a)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> list(a)
[]
```

Use `list()` to copy the results to a list object, or better still, use a list comprehension instead of `map()`:

```
a = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:-

```
inputparam='100 2 300'
a = [int(i) for i in inputparam.split()]
maxNo=max(a)
sumno=sum(a)
```